# How to add a Variable to a File Path using Java in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, variables, path

I want to declare a variable `"i"` in the image's path in order to use a `"FOR LOOP"` to scan 5 images in a matching process, but can't do it in Linux.

This was my line in Windows and it worked by putting a forward slash before the variable to separate it or to be realized as a variable:

```java
for (i=1 ; i<=5 ; i++)
{
    ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\Saved\\stage\\/"+i+".bmp"));
}
```

But in Linux the path itself contains forward slashes, what should i put before the variable?
`ImageIO.read(new File("/home/pi/Desktop/“+i+”.bmp"));`

Comment: Have a look at [java.nio.Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html). Don't use `java.util.File` anymore if you don't have to.

Comment: You do it the exact same way: you write a loop and turn the loop counter into a string which you then put at the right place to get a valid file name. Thus I really have no idea what you are struggling with.

Comment: In windows when the paths are separated by double back slashes “\\” i could use a single forward slash “/“ before the variable “i” in order to separate it from the path and declare it as a variable like this: \\stage\\/"+i+".bmp" .. But in linux, paths are separated by forward slashes “/“.. what should i put before the “+i+” ??

Comment: That forward slash in your code is entirely unnecessary. Why do you think it is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same way for Linux:

```
for (i=1 ; i<=5 ; i++) {
  ImageIO.read(new File("/home/pi/Desktop/" + i + ".bmp"));
}
```

Comment: In windows when the paths are separated by double back slashes “\\” i could use a single forward slash “/“ before the variable “i” in order to separate it from the path and declare it as a variable like this: \\stage\\/"+i+".bmp" .. But in linux, paths are separated by forward slashes “/“.. what should i put before the “+i+” ??

Comment: Read the answer.  No point saying the same thing again.  If you need clarification, ask a specific question.